# Cocoapods podspec with dependencies issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, mbprogresshud, svprogresshud

What I need is create a Pod that will have several other Pods (MBProgressHUD, SVProgressHUD) included in as a dependencies. So my goal is to have a MultiProgressHUD (so for example show different progress huds depending on configuration)
I have created a CocoaPods Project using pod lib create.
I have made the steps provided by CocoaPods and I have my project here:

https://github.com/dahiri-farid/PSMultiProgressHUD

When I do:

```
`pod lib lint PSMultiProgressHUD.podspec `
```

I get:

```
`PSMultiProgressHUD passed validation.`
```

My concern is that in the generated project I don't have the sources of the linked dependencies pods. So the biggest concern is for example that how I will develop my Pod if I can not even compile it because I don't have the dependecies sources. I have tried many commands and read some docs, but did not found usefull info. So can anyone please help me on that? Or explain me the workflow with CocoaPods dependencies?